# jQuery script stops clicks from registering

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm having an issue with a CSS/jQuery combination.

The setup is the following: I have a series of divs that have a CSS class assigned to it. That class triggers a change in margin-top when hovered, along with a CSS transition to make it a smooth animation.

I also have a jQuery script running to automatically reposition the contents of a child so that its content always appears centered vertically.

Everything does what it is supposed to do, but the problem arises when I hover over the first block and the animation starts playing, but then move my mouse to the second block to click that one. The click will not register until the animation in the first block is done playing.

The moment I turn off the script, the clicks go through the moment I click, regardless of the animation.

The script:

```
/* Grid hover */
$(document).on('mouseover', '.grid-item', function(e) {
    var positionSingle = ( $(this).children('.caption-bg').height() / 2 ) - ( $(this).children('.caption').height() / 2 ) - 16;
    $(this).find('.caption').css( "margin-top", positionSingle );
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.grid-item', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.caption').css( "margin-top", ("-70px") );
});
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code needed to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not providing a fiddle, I cannot tell for sure.

But I think it is because you are not using the right pair of events.

The opposite of **mouseover** is not **mouseleave** but **mouseout**.

So you should either be using:

- mouseenter/mouseleave
- mouseover/mouseout

Here is the documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added this, as well as some CSS pointer-events, and the combination of these two appears to have fixed it.